# Мне нужен бот на python, который мог бы пересылать введенные в него сообщения с фото мне в личку телеграма

Tags: python, бот, telegram

нашел такой код:

```py
token = ''
bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)
chat_id = ''


@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True)
def echo_message(message):
    bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, text=message.text)

bot.polling()
```

но его проблема в том, что он не умеет пересылать фото. Такое вообще возможно сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Как реализовать одновременный пересыл фотографии с текстом определенному пользователю я пока не знаю, не смогу добиться, но вот пересыл отдельно фотографии смог.

Код пересыла фотографии:

```
@tb.message_handler(content_types=['photo'])
def handler_file(message):
    import pathlib
    from pathlib import Path
    Path(f'files/{message.chat.id}/').mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
    if message.content_type == 'photo':
        file_info = tb.get_file(message.photo[len(message.photo) - 1].file_id)
        downloaded_file = tb.download_file(file_info.file_path)
        src = f'files/{message.chat.id}/' + file_info.file_path.replace('photos/', '')
        with open(src, 'wb') as new_file:
            new_file.write(downloaded_file)
        tb.send_photo(твой id, open(src, 'rb'))
        file = pathlib.Path(f'{src}')
        file.unlink()
```

Данный код сначала сохраняет фотографию на пк, после чего отправляет определенному пользователю. В данном случае тому, чей id Вы укажете в программе.

Последние две строчки очищают папку от того файла, что в нее закачал пк от пользователя